# NSString to int issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, nsstring

When I want to convert `NSString` to `int`
I use:

```
[string intValue];
```

But how to determine if string is `int` value? for instance to avoid situations like this:

```
[@"hhhuuukkk" intValue];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int value;
NSString *s = @"huuuk";
if([[NSScanner scannerWithString:s] scanInt:&value]) {
    //Is int value
}
else {
    //Is not int value
}
```

Edit: added isAtEnd check according to Martin R's suggestion. This will make sure it is only digits in the whole string.

```
int value;
NSString *s = @"huuuk";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:s];
if([scanner scanInt:&value] && [scanner isAtEnd]) {
    //Is int value
}
else {
    //Is not int value
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why this answer is downvoted, it looks correct to me. - You could even *improve* the solution by adding a check for `[scanner isAtEnd]`, so that the input "123foo" is also recognized as wrong.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, this is surely better than the "I know, I'll just use regexes" approach (also presented above)...

Comment: But now is does not compile :-)

Comment: martin-r: oops, I made 2 versions instead now

Answer (score 2):

The C way: use `strtol()` and check `errno`:

```
errno = 0;
int n = strtol(str.UTF8String, NULL, 0);
if (errno != 0) {
    perror("strtol");
    // or handle error otherwise
}
```

The Cocoa way: use `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];
NSNumber *num = nil;
NSError *err = nil;
NSRange r = NSMakeRange(0, str.length);

[fmt getObjectValue:&num forString:str range:&r error:&err];
if (err != nil) {
    // handle error
} else {
    int n = [num intValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
 NSNumber * amt = [f numberFromString:@"STRING"];

 if(amt)
 { 
        // convert to int if you want to like you have done in your que.

       //valid amount
 }
 else
 {
     // not valid
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *yourStr = @"hhhuuukkk";
NSString *regx = @"(-){0,1}(([0-9]+)(.)){0,1}([0-9]+)";
NSPredicate *chekNumeric = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regx];
BOOL isNumber = [chekNumeric evaluateWithObject:yourStr];

if(isNumber)
{
  // Your String has only numeric value convert it to intger;
}
else
{
  // Your String has NOT only numeric value also others;
}
```

For only **integer** value change **Rgex** pattern to `^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$` ;

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *stringValue = @"hhhuuukkk";
if ([[NSScanner scannerWithString:stringValue] scanInt:nil]) {
    //Is int value
}
else{
    //Is not int value
}
```

`[[NSScanner scannerWithString:stringValue] scanInt:nil]` will check if "stringValue" has an integer value.

It returns a BOOL indicating whether or not it found a suitable int value.

Comment: See www.jensolsson.se's answer above.

Comment: As Martin noted already, this will also accept `@"123hhhuuukkk"` as `int`.